# Are there females in Durmstrang?

Tags: harry-potter, triwizard-tournament

In the 4th Harry Potter book I read that Poliakoff (Durmstrang student) when he spotted Harry Potter he pointed Harry's scar to a girl standing next to him, this occurence happened when they first arrived at Hogwarts for the Triwizard tournament. The girl was never identified as a Hogwart, Beauxbaton or Durmstrang student. Is there canon evidence of what school she came from and can females attend Durmstrang?

Also the wikia says the girl is from Durmstrang, but they don't give evidence. Someone told me that Durmstrang was an all-male school, but I assumed it was since no females are known that have joined.